# ResultSet.next() Throwing SQLException: Result Set Closed

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I've tried to debug the code and read the Oracle doc and I don't see any reason why the result set would be closed.

```
 Statement statement = DatabaseConnector.connect();
    String sql = "Select * from Room where Room_Type like '*"+roomType+"*' "+availability;
    boolean foundResults = statement.execute(sql);
    if(foundResults){
    ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
    StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
    if(rs!=null){
    while(rs.next()){
```

Comment: What is the output of `System.out.println(sql)`?

Comment: "Select * from Room where Room_Type like '*Double*' ;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RE: SQLException**

I'm not quite sure what `DatabaseConnector` is supposed to do in the question code, but the following test code works for me.

**RE: Wildcard character**

When using the LIKE operator in a query *from within the Access application itself* then the asterisk `*` is the wildcard character to use. When querying an ACE (Access) database *from some other application* one needs to use the "standard" percent `%` wildcard character. Note that the following code uses `%`; using `*` won't work here.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCQuery {
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" + 
                    "Dbq=C:\\Users\\Public\\Database1.accdb;");
            String RoomTypeToMatch = "suite";
            PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT Room_No, Room_Type " +
                    "FROM Room WHERE Room_Type LIKE ?"
                    );
            s.setString(1, "%" + RoomTypeToMatch + "%");
            s.execute();
            ResultSet rs = s.getResultSet();
            if (rs!=null)
            {
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    System.out.println("[Room_No]: " + rs.getString(1) +
                            ", [Room_Type]: " + rs.getString(2));
                }
            }
            s.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank yo very much @GordThompson especially for explaining that * wildcard character works only on the database and I must use % pragmatically that was my problem

Answer (score 0):

`SQL` `LIKE` wildcard charcaters are represented as `%` not `*`

```
String sql = 
    "Select * from Room where Room_Type like '%"+roomType+ "%' "+availability;
```

Aside: Always use a PreparedStatement to project against SQL Injection attacks

Comment: Remember this is MS Acess not Oracle, I tested with * on the DB and it worked

Comment: Looks like a JDBC rather than DB issue. Aside from that the wildcard characters are not appearing in the SQL query...

Comment: They are appearing, I just couldn't paste them here